# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib OpenCV C++ MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, clion

I've been trying to make OpenCV (3.4.0) work on MacOS (10.11.6) with C++.

I've tried various ways for the installation, but ended up "succeeding" by following [this](https://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/) guide.

I am now trying to run the following example project in CLion:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The project builds fine, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
```

I've been looking around and the only related problems I could find were in connection with PHP.
Any sort of help or pointer in the right direction is highly appreciated!
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCV requires the [libjpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libjpeg) library to read your jpg file, and it is dynamically loaded (like a DLL) when you run your program. The program searches that dynamic library at a predefined path - `/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib`, and most likely you don't have this file there.

The first step is to find this library on your computer, which you can do by running:

```
sudo find / -name 'libjpeg.*'
```

If nothing is found (like it happened to me), you have several options: build the library from source code, find a pre-built library and download it, or install it from a package manager (like brew or MacPorts). Probably I would try brew first. Note: you probably need version 9 of the libjpeg library.

`brew install libjpeg` command worked for me. (you need to [install brew](https://brew.sh) first).

Step 2: when you get the library, you need to make sure that the program can find it. Usually there's a way to override the hardcoded path like `/usr/local/opt` at build time using some build script variable somewhere in the OpenCV build scripts. An easier way might be to either install it where it expects it to be (at `/usr/local/opt`), or make a symlink from that path to a real location.

I've used brew and it actually installed it at the expected path:

`bash-3.2$ pwd
/usr/local/opt/libjpeg/lib
bash-3.2$ ls
libjpeg.9.dylib libjpeg.a   libjpeg.dylib   pkgconfig
bash-3.2$ brew info libjpeg
jpeg: stable 9c (bottled)
Image manipulation library
http://www.ijg.org
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9c (21 files, 724.6KB) *`

Comment: Wow! Thanks for a really great answer already battlmonstr!
Running the find command I actually get a lot of results... seems like it's just not in the right place! I even have the same library from hombrew, but in a different place...
How exactly would I go about making a symlink to a real location (I suspect you mean one of the locations where the needed dynamic library is already existent)?

Comment: `sudo ln -s "<existing path>" "<new link path>"`

need "sudo" on mac for locations like /usr/local

Comment: You're my hero! Thanks so much! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ends up here after switching to Apple Silicon and getting stumped, I'm leaving this comment as well, though it is unrelated to OpenCV, just libjpeg in general.

### You may need to set flags.

On a different project a few months later I had to update dependencies again after not touching the project on the new M2 machine. I did all of the above, it was symlinked, but still no joy. Copying and pasting the entire node_modules folder to the new project worked, but didn't understand why. So I ran the above command in the accepted answer;

> brew info libjpeg

and got this output which made me remember doing this when the original issue came up a few months ago on the first project after the ARM architecture upgrade:

> ==> Caveats jpeg is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew, because it conflicts with `jpeg-turbo`.
>
> If you need to have jpeg first in your PATH, run:
> echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/jpeg/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
>
> **For compilers to find jpeg you may need to set:**
> export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/jpeg/lib"
> export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/jpeg/include"

The first caveat was done already, but the flags needed to be set again on this project, I guess. Deleted the node_modules folder, set the flags, npm install, and voila: no errors (for that at least).